# Shutter button depresses all the way, but does not fire the shutter, and the film advance lever is stuck - Konica Autoreflex T

Tags: film, troubleshooting, shutter, konica, mechanical-shutter

I moved the shutter speed dial while the film transport lever was half-cocked and now the shutter does not work. Shutter depresses all the way and film transport lever does not move from the starting position. I know how to remove the mirror box because I had just replaced a corroded wire. Will removing the mirror box and putting it back fix the shutter? Or is it the shutter that need to be fixed?

Help is much appreciated, thanks.